# C# generics: using class generic in where clause of method generic

Tags: c#, generics, .net-2.0

Can anyone explain why isn't this possible (at least in .Net 2.0):

```
public class A<T>
{
    public void Method<U>() where U : T
    {
        ...
    }
}

...

A<K> obj = new A<K>();
obj.Method<J>();
```

with K being the superclass of J

**EDIT**

I've tried to simplify the problem in order to make the question more legible, but I've clearly overdo that. Sorry!

My problem is a little more specific I guess. This is my code (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2944394/43046)):

```
public class Container<T>
{
    private static class PerType<U> where U : T
    {
        public static U item;
    }

    public U Get<U>() where U : T
    {
        return PerType<U>.item;
    }

    public void Set<U>(U newItem) where U : T
    {
        PerType<U>.item = newItem;
    }
}
```

and I'm getting this error:

> Container.cs(13,24): error CS0305: Using the generic type
>   `Container<T>.PerType<U>' requires`2' type argument(s)

Comment: It is possible in 4.0. Not very useful, because you do not use the type parameter in the signature, but definitely possible.

Comment: It does work, even in .NET 2.0.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I have edited the question. Sorry.

Comment: Even after edit, the code works perfectly fine.

Comment: Well, I definitely get the error above. This happens inside Unity which uses Mono compiler. I don't know if it might have something to do with it.

Comment: it seems to be something related with the compiler indeed:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/262475/c-generics-using-class-generic-in-where-clause-of.html
I'll try to confirm it tomorrow at the office. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've just confirmed it. adding the "Container<T>." prefix solves the problem. it should be caused by some bug in Mono C# compiler.

Comment: Be careful: you've got an *instance* of `Container<T>` that provides access to *static* storage. That means that all `Container<T>` instances share the same storage, which is likely to be in error.  I'd recommend making `Container<T>` a singleton to clarify that there is really only one instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually it is possible. This code compiles and runs just fine:

```
public class A<T>
{
    public void Act<U>() where U : T
    {
        Console.Write("a");
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  A<IEnumerable> a = new A<IEnumerable>();
  a.Act<List<int>>();
}
```

What is not possible is using covariance / contravariance in generics, as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<Derived> d = new List<Derived>();
IEnumerable<Base> b = d;
```

Comment: still, it compiles and works (of course U Item will remain a null at all times - you didnt provide a way to initialize your PertTyp class / its item field)

Comment: Please check my latest comment to my question.
The initialization is supposed to be done by calling the Set method.
obj.Set<J>(jObj)
The PerType class should be static. I've removed it while debugging. I've edited the question to add the keyword again.

Comment: it still works.. maybe you should provide ur entire complete code?

Comment: This is my entire code. There is really nothing more. I've started a new Unity project with just this Class and it gives the same error. Maybe it is a Mono or Unity specific error. I'll try to test it in other platforms. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It looks like it can eventually be related with the Mono compiler in Unity.
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/262475/c-generics-using-class-generic-in-where-clause-of.html
I'll try to further confirm this hypothesis tomorrow. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've just confirmed it. adding the "Container<T>." prefix solves the problem. it should be caused by some bug in Mono C# compiler.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me (VS 2008).

Do you have a problem with a class visibility? (class not public, wrong namespace)

Which error message are you getting?

---

**UPDATE**

Given your implementation of `Container<T>` I can write

```
class A { }
class B : A { }

class Test
{
    public void MethodName( )
    {
        var obj = new Container<A>();
        obj.Set(new B());
    }
}
```

This works perfectly. Are you sure that `B` derives from `A`? Note that for instance `List<B>` does NOT derive from `List<A>` (see YavgenyP's answer).

---

The error message could be a hint, telling you that there exists another `Container<T>` in another namespace requiring a second type argument for `PerType<U, X??? >`.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: This is probably a bug with Mono compiler or Unity. I've asked this same question in their Q&A system. Currently I have no way to test this (I will check it tomorrow at the office), but it seems to be a problem with the compiler:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/262475/c-generics-using-class-generic-in-where-clause-of.html

Thanks for your insight though.

Comment: I've just confirmed it. adding the "Container<T>." prefix solves the problem. it should be caused by some bug in Mono C# compiler.