# Use Type as a key in dictionary C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I am stuck creating inventory in a Unity3D game.

I have several `Food` classes which are extending a base class. 
I want to put them in a dictionary

```
Dictionary <Types, int> inventory;
```

And then I want to use it as

```
inventory[getType(selectedObject)]
```

How to make it working?

Or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: _How to make it working?_ First of all you should tell us what issue you're facing :)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2944299

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe following is what you are looking for. To begin with, you have a Typo in the code. It is `Type` and NOT `Types`.

To get the type of an object, you could use [.GetType()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?view=netframework-4.8) method. For example,

```
var obj = new List<int>();
Dictionary <Type, int> inventory = new Dictionary<Type,int>();
inventory.Add(obj.GetType(),1);
```

Comment: Wow, I got in love in stackoverflow. An answer in 3 minutes is really cool!!!

Comment: Could you please tell me, if it is a good solution in my case?

Comment: @diukqnhffvy it depends on your requirement. If, for instance, you have multiple instances of same class (Food1,Food2,Food1), then you would not able to add two keys with same type as Dictionary would not allow duplicate keys

Comment: @diukqnhffvy Glad to help you. Kindly mark it as answer if it helped you resolve the issue https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers